# How do you costumize design in bought wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress

I have a question which I never figured out. If I bought template, lets say Avada or Enfold. How do I customize css? Should I change in css files how I want or there is better way? I saw many websites using avada or enfold in source code, but the website looks way different than original. Which way is best to customize template? Change headers,footer and etc..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to customize your theme is ***Child Theme***. You can do it on your own. Thanks to that you will be sure that you don't modify original files but only something like "copy" which overwrite your original files.
Avada Theme actually has it built-in. After purchase you will receive Avada_Full_Package with a original theme and his child.

One sentence from Avada's documentation: *"Always use a child theme if you are modifying core code. "*

More information about **Avada Child Theme**: 
https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/special-features/avada-child-theme/

More information about **Child Themes** and **DIY** in WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes